# Domain of solved Differential equation?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

So I have differential equation $dy/{dx}=({-6x^2})/y$. By separation, I solve this differential equation to the point I have $y^2= -4x^3+c$.

Should the solution to the equation be $y= \sqrt{-4x^3+c}$ or $y=± \sqrt{-4x^3+c}$?

The reason I am confused is because I am also asked to find the solution of the equation, given that $f(1) = 2$.

Comment: If it were the latter, then y(1) would be a not single-valued function.  Therefore, you should pick whichever solution can possibly go through the initial data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that $f(1) = 2$ allows you to find $c$. We must have $(2)^2 = -4(1)^3+c$, so $c=8$. Only $$f(x) = \sqrt{-4x^3 + 8}$$ works to satisfy the boundary condition. Also note the solution is only valid for $x \leq 2^{1/3}$.

Answer (score 1):

When solving a differential equation, you will get a family of solutions. However, once you fix an initial value, then by the existence and uniqueness theorem you will have one unique solution.

In your case, when you plug in the initial condition to $y^2 = -4x^3 +c$ to get $y^2= -4x^3+6$ which means $y$ can either be $\sqrt{-4x^3+6}$ or $-\sqrt{-4x^3+6}$. But since $y(1)=2$ then  your answer can only be $y= \sqrt{-4x^3+6}$ because the other will give you $-2$ when you plug in $x=1$.

Comment: It should be 8 not 6.